# How to read a string containing a '\' using opencsv?

Tags: java, opencsv

When I'm reading a csv-file using opencsv it doesn't work properly when encountering a '\' at the end of a string. It makes the " part of the string, instead of the '\' as I want to. I guess there must be some method to add another '\' to have it escape the '\'-character instead? *Without* having to manually edit the csv-file. I have searched but not found anything.

To clarify my problem, it looks like this:

**csv-file**

```
"A",       "B",        "C",       "D"
"value 1", "value 2",  "value 3", "value 4"
"value 5", "value 6\", "value 7", "value 8"
```

My code looks like this (not really, but it shows my problem):

```
String inFile = "in.csv";
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(inFile));
String[] line;

while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; line.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + line[i]);
    }
}
```

I want this to parse into a String[] with 4 elements each, for each row, but the last row parses only into two elements, as shown in the output below.

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
1 value 1
2 value 2
3 value 3
4 value 4
1 value 5
2 value 6",value 7,value 8
```

I have tried to change the reader to:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile), "UTF-8"));
```

but without any luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe change the escape character in the constructor of the Reader?

```
CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile)), ',', '"', '|')
```

This is assuming `|` is not used in your CSV file

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm able to read that line as supposed to. However, I have the character **|** in the file also. Is there any way to skip the escape character?

Comment: Try `'\0'`. I think this is invalid for CVS

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly the answer to my problem

Comment: How to read commas if it is  contained within the value ? EX: "A","user,k","B"

Comment: @user000001 can you help plz?

Comment: @ChendurPandian: It should work if the values are inside double quotes as you showed. If not create a minimal reproducible example that shows how it doesn't work properly in your case and ask a new question about that

Answer (score 9):

More cleaner and recommended solution is to use `RFC4180Parser` instead of default `CSVParser`:

```
String csv = "come,csv,string";
RFC4180Parser rfc4180Parser = new RFC4180ParserBuilder().build();
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new StringReader(csv)).withCSVParser(rfc4180Parser).build();
```

Reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/support-requests/50/

Comment: What is `writer`?

Answer (score 4):

The backslash is for escaping the `"` because some values may contain a `"` character, and without the backslash you would not be able to have the character included.

So if you want to use `\` you need to escape it with `\` too, just like you would do to have it in a regular Java String.

```
"A",       "B",         "C",       "D"
"value 1", "value 2",   "value 3", "value 4"
"value 5", "value 6\\", "value 7", "value 8"
```

Either you modify your CSV file or you use another constructor from [CSVReader](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html#CSVReader%28java.io.Reader,%20char,%20char%29) from which you can choose the escape character

Comment: User explicitly states they cannot modify the csv. Imagine this is dirty data coming in from an outside source.