# OpenCSV - readAll function gives error with special characters

Tags: java, special-characters, opencsv

I am trying to read a CSV file using the OpenCSV library. My data is in the following format in the CSV.

```
"No", "Name", "Address", "Date"
"1", "Harry", "River's Drive", "02/11/2016 00:00:01"
"2", "Tom", "Cover's Park", "03/11/2016 00:00:01"
```

It can have special characters. All works well when I use the readAll() from OpenCSV. However it fails to read the character ' in the data and gives error. Is there any way to escape and retain that character?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a string containing a '\' using opencsv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14819626/how-to-read-a-string-containing-a-using-opencsv)

Comment: please attach a sample of the code you are using to read the data so we can see what you have defined for the quotation character (and other settings).